# Cursor in trigger is fetching null values (binary IDs)

Tags: database, triggers, mariadb

I am trying to create an AFTER INSERT trigger on a table that does the following:

1. get a cursor on "users" based on a simple where constraint.
2. iterate over the cursor items and insert into or update "last_syncs" using the fetched IDs.

here's the trigger code:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `court_groups_update_last_syncs_on_insert`
AFTER INSERT ON `court_groups` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
   DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
   DECLARE val INT;
   DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT users.id FROM users where users.country_id = NEW.country_id;
   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET done=1;

   OPEN cur;
   cur_loop: LOOP
      IF done THEN
         LEAVE cur_loop;
      END IF;
   FETCH cur INTO val;
   INSERT INTO last_syncs (user_id, table_name) VALUES (val,'court_groups') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE last_syncs.timestamp = NOW();
   END LOOP;
   CLOSE cur; 
END
```

The problem is that the cursor is fetching NULL values.

I've checked previous answers to the same problem and most of them said that having two variables with the same name can cause problems, but I have nothing like that in my code.

**Keep in mind that all IDs in the database are in binary form, could this be the problem?**

I am using MariaDB 10.1.13.

Comment: Do you really need a cursor?. Can you post `users` table structure?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use cursors if you can avoid them.

The entire Trigger can be simplified to one statement, something like:

```
INSERT INTO last_syncs (user_id, table_name, timestamp)
    SELECT id, 'court_groups', NOW()
        FROM users
        where country_id = NEW.country_id
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE timestamp = VALUES(timestamp);
```

(I am unclear of the intent of the Trigger, so I may have some mistakes.)

Comment: I had to move the ON DUPLICATE statement to the end, but it works! thanks a lot, works like a charm.